# .net oledb error when read excel file

Tags: asp.net, excel, window

Below is my code use for read excel file.
I test in my pc localhost and 3 window server.
Localhost and 1 of the server work fine, the other 2 server will return error

`object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

3 server folder permission are same and excel file exists at correct path.
I have no idea why the error occur at certain server.

### VB.net Code

```
Dim objExcelConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

objExcelConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & str_FilePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"""

Try
    objExcelConn.Open()   <------ Where the error occur
Catch ex As Exception
    Throw (New Exception(ex.InnerException.Message))
End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will have excel installed on your server.
The problem is that you don't have driver of excel over the server.
Try to download the .dll and run your application again.

Comment: What .dll installer i should download ?

All server has been installed `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0` Driver.

Comment: try to see what is there in the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: All the server have `Msjet40.dll`. The problem still occur. :-S

Comment: Problem Solve. 

Install `Microsoft.Jet.OLEBD.4.0` at server and change the connection string from 

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & str_FilePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"` 

to

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & str_FilePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1"`. `OLEDB.12.0` use in 64 bit windows enviroments.